# Does resolution affect movement speed in Call of Cthulhu: Dark Corners of the Earth?

Tags: pc, version-differences, call-of-cthulhu-dcote

According to [a review on GameFAQs](https://www.gamefaqs.com/ps2/437029-silent-hill-2/faqs/22833) the selected resolution affects character's movement speed. According to the [PC Gaming Wiki](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Call_of_Cthulhu:_Dark_Corners_of_the_Earth#References) the bug is fixed in the Steam version, but on the other hand [the unofficial patch](http://dcotetools.sucklead.com/p/dcotepatch.html) that fixes bugs and restores removed features only works with the retail version.

> I spent a large amount of time constantly reloading that particular
>   chase scene. After yet another death at the hands of that creature I
>   found out something most curious and ill-conceived about the game. The
>   resolution at which you play the game affects the speed of which Jack [the player character]
>   runs.